# How to write user scripts so they work in both Opera and Greasemonkey

Tags: greasemonkey, opera, userscripts

I'm getting into user scripts at the moment. I know Opera is compatible with many aspects of Greasemonkey scripts, but not so much with other aspects.

The [GM functions emulation script](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/operaStuff/userJavaScript.html) will be required on Opera, and at the start I have

```
if(window.opera) {
    var unsafeWindow = window;
}
```

But beyond that, what other things should I keep in mind if I want my scripts to run in both?

Comment: I've done this before, but I have no advice other than what you've put in your question already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My [Endless Tweets](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/24398) user script works equally well in Firefox, WebKit and Opera.

I'm using [a compatibility script I wrote myself](http://github.com/mislav/user-scripts/blob/master/toolkit/gm_functions.js) which provides `GM_getValue`, `GM_setValue`, `GM_xmlhttpRequest`, `GM_addStyle` and `GM_log`.

However, I don't like using the "GM_" prefix since the user script is cross-platform, so the scripts has this API:

```
getValue()
setValue()
xhr()
addCSS()
log()
```

Check the rest of [the toolkit](http://github.com/mislav/user-scripts/blob/master/toolkit/toolkit.js) for more useful functions when writing user scripts.